# How do I fix my justify content issue in CSS flexbox? Space-between not working properly

Tags: html, css

**EDIT: Turns out my code works. I just was using a smaller screen computer to view the code. Once I moved it to a larger sized screen the space-between worked completely fine. I thought I was going crazy, but figured out the issue**

For some reason, my justify-content: space-between isn't separating my items. The h1, button, and select tags in the .controls class are all next to each other when they should be spaced out with space-between

Here is my HTML & CSS and under .controls class justify-content space between isn't spacing the items. Note I also have 2 other sections in my HTML labeled snare and hihat, but the HTML above is only showing the kick section

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

i,
svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.kick-pad,
.snare-pad,
.hihat-pad {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 1rem 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hihat-track,
.snare-track,
.kick-track {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.sequencer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.kick,
.snare,
.hihat {
  display: flex;
}

.controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-self: center;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0rem 2rem;
}

.controls button {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.pad {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.play {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  background: rgb(88, 88, 88);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

select {
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sequencer">
      <div class="kick-track">
        <div class="controls">
          <h1>Kick</h1>
          <button data-track="0" class="mute kick-volume">
            <i class="fas fa-volume-mute"></i>
          </button>
          <select name="kick-select" id="kick-select">
            <option value="./sounds/kick-classic.wav">Classic Kick</option>
            <option value="./sounds/kick-808.wav">808 Kick</option>
            <option value="./sounds/kick-heavy.wav">Kick Heavy</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="kick">
          <div class="pad kick-pad b0"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b1"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b2"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b3"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b4"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b5"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b6"></div>
          <div class="pad kick-pad b7"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is an image of what it current looks like and I don't know why they are stuck side by side even though I am using justify-content:space-between.
[image]

Comment: can you add a sketch of how you want this to look?

Comment: just need some spacing between. Right now they are literally touching side by side, which I don't understand why. Pretend each tag inside the controls div had a left and right margin of 5rem. That's what I'm trying to achieve, but the css isn't doing that for me

Comment: provide a sketch

Comment: I added a photo above showing what it currently looks like. I need those elements to have space between them.

Comment: There's no available empty space for `justify-content: space-between;` to take effect. to **see** the effect remove `.kick`

Comment: The problem is I have another div next to it <div class="kick">
         

so when I remove the flex on .kick it ruins my design for this section.

Comment: remove flex and justify content from kick-track class then it spcaes them equally.

Comment: I need .kick div to be on the same row as .controls

Comment: oh wow I realized what was wrong. The display on my smaller screen didn't space them out, but I just moved my code to a bigger desktop and it works out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding some kind of width to the class like

`.controls { width: 20vw; }` or `.controls { width: 100%; }`